Display and automatically update the current version of Draw.io diagramm inside a the diagramm itself
In one of my projects I am using the Confluence Plugin draw.io (https://www.drawio.com/).
I am quite often exporting the diagram as a PNG from my Confluence page and will send it via E-Mail to different stakeholders. In order for stakeholders to distinguish the different versions of the png I am right now manually updating the version of the document and increment it on every change.
Has draw.io the feature to automatically extract the version information of the confluence history or any other feature, so that you can automatically update the version number on the page. It already happened to me, that I just forgot to update the version information

I have the same issue - I was unable to find the feature in the feature requests or documentation, so I have created a feature request: https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/4436

draw.io for Confluence DC has %version%, see https://www.drawio.com/doc/faq/predefined-placeholders.

Many thanks. I tried it out. Works like charm.
